# Use here-document in a one-liner?

Tags: bash, here-document

I have a simple script that executes commands on remote host using `ssh` and a here-document.

I was trying to do it with a one-liner at command line but I couldn't figure out how to do the here-document outside of a script. Is it possible? I spent some time googling and reading documentation about here-documents, but it wasn't coming to me.

This script works fine - I needed the here-document section in order to run `awk` remotely via ssh but I usually like to do one-liners for simple stuff:

```
#!/bin/bash
# it looks up all my hosts with 'db' in the name
# then gets the PID of any rsyncs running as user 'research'
# and pumps them into xargs

getHosts=(`curl --silent "http://assetts.lab/all_hosts" | grep -v ^# | awk -F" " '{print$1}'|grep db`)
for BOX in ${getHosts[@]};do
    echo "$BOX: "
    ssh -T sshUser@$BOX <<"EOF"
ps -ef | egrep "rsync|iasync" | awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ "research") print $2}'|sudo xargs -i ps -fp '{}'
#ps -ef | egrep "rsync|iasync" | awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ "research") print $2}'|sudo xargs -i kill '{}'
EOF
    echo
done
```

I'm probably missing something simple...
Anyway thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Your current code is simple and readable. You already have 2 kinds of quotes in the remote command: using some more condensed form will make your code "clever", and that's usually contrary to maintainable

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a need to do anything about the use of a here-document, but I *do* see that you can simplify other things in your script quite a bit (which in turn makes the here-document obsolete).

First of all, the pipeline to populate your `getHosts` array may be simplified (there is seldom a reason to pipe `grep` into `awk`), and the whole array can be removed:

```bsh
curl -s 'http://assetts.lab/all_hosts' |
awk -F ' ' '!/^#/ && $1 ~ /db/ { print $1 }' |
while IFS= read -r remote; do
   # rest of code
done
```

Here I have combined your `grep`+`awk`+`grep` command into a single `awk` command.  I've also let the `awk` command feed the hostnames directly into the loop instead of storing them in an intermediate variable.

Inside the loop, it looks as if you're wanting to get information about a `rsync` or `iasync` process belonging to a `research` user.

This is best done with `pgrep`:

```bsh
pgrep -l -U research 'rsync|iasync'
```

To signal these processes, use `pkill` in place of `pgrep` and drop the `-l` option.

The full script the becomes:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

curl -s 'http://assetts.lab/all_hosts' |
awk -F ' ' '!/^#/ && $1 ~ /db/ { print $1 }' |
while IFS= read -r remote; do
   printf 'Processing host "%s"\n' "$remote"
   ssh "$remote" 'pgrep -l -U research "rsync|iasync"'
done
```

Or, using `xargs`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

curl -s 'http://assetts.lab/all_hosts' |
awk -F ' ' '!/^#/ && $1 ~ /db/ { print $1 }' |
xargs -I {} sh -c '
   printf "Processing host \"%s\"\n" "$1"
   ssh "$1" "pgrep -l -U research \"rsync|iasync\""' sh {}
```

If your `xargs` supports it, this could be made to run several `sh -c` processes at once with `-P n`, where `n` is the number of concurrent `sh -c` command that `xargs` should keep running.

Answer (score 0):

The EOF bash feature is basically for use as you do in your example, ie in order to send multiple lines of text to another command.

If you want this as a one-liner, the EOF has to go.

In order to execute a command on a remote host using ssh, all you need to do is:

```
ssh host command
```

For example:

```
ssh host "ls -alh"
```

will run the command on host and return the output on the console.

Your example code could be rewritten in a one line if you take note of how you use the quotation marks, something like this:

```
ssh host "ps -ef | egrep 'rsync|iasync' | awk -F' ' '{if (\$1 ~ \"research\") print \$2}'"
```

This double-quoted string puts the arguments to individual commands in single-quotes.  When more double-quotes are needed (the `"research`" pattern), they have to be escaped with a `\`, and so do the `$` characters.

Comment: the awk doesn't actually work on the remote host when used this way - this is *why* I used heredocs to begin with

#works:

`$ ssh luser@box "ps -ef | egrep 'rsync|iasync'"
luser    7457  7454  0 11:44 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef | egrep 'rsync|iasync'
luser    7476  7457  0 11:44 ?        00:00:00 egrep rsync|iasync`

# no worky
`
$ssh luser@box "ps -ef | egrep 'rsync|iasync' | awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ "research") print $2}'"

Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
`

Comment: ^^ sorry I don't yet know how to format in comments :( ^^

Comment: using a heredoc sends the doc content to stdin, this is different to adding an argument to ssh. The one-liner equivalent to a heredoc would be a herestring, i.e. using a triple chevron: ssh host <<<''commands"